# SimpleDateFormat to java.time

Tags: java, time, simpledateformat, datetime-format

I'm trying to understand how the Java 8 date/time framework works.
I'm actually using SimpleDateFormat this way to return milliseconds given a string:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS").parse(builder.toString()).getTime();
```

What would it become with the new classes in Java 8?

Comment: Your desired format is close to the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. I strongly recommend sticking with the standard formats rather than invent your own. The standard is wisely designed to avoid ambiguities. And these are used by default in java.time classes for parsing/generating strings. Your format is close to the “basic” version, minimizing use of separators. To comply fully, (a) insert a `T` between the year-month-day and the hour-minute-second portions, and (b) insert a comma (preferably) or a full-stop (period) before the fractional second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you specified cannot work in Java-8. The problem has been [fixed in Java-9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085) with seemingly no backport, but Java-9 is not yet released.

Possible **workarounds for Java-8** either include awkward string preprocessing, that is inserting a decimal separator before the fraction part or downloading other 3rd-party-libraries (where the parsers are probably still quicker than in Java-9 according to my observations):

**String preprocessing**

```
String mydate = "20130812214600025";
String adjustedInput = new StringBuilder(mydate).insert(14, '.').toString();
ZonedDateTime date =
    ZonedDateTime.parse(
        adjustedInput,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS").withZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault()));
System.out.println(date); // 2013-08-12T21:46:00.025+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
System.out.println(date.toInstant().toEpochMilli()); // 1376336760025
```

**Joda-Time**:

```
String mydate = "20130812214600025";
DateTime date =
    DateTime.parse(
        mydate,
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"));
System.out.println(date); // 2013-08-12T21:46:00.025+02:00
System.out.println(date.toInstant().getMillis()); // 1376336760025
```

**My library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J)**

```
long millisSinceUnix =
    ChronoFormatter.ofPattern(
        "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS",
        PatternType.CLDR,
        Locale.ROOT,
        Moment.axis(TemporalType.MILLIS_SINCE_UNIX)
    ).with(Timezone.ofSystem()).parse(mydate).longValue();
System.out.println(millisSinceUnix); // 1376336760025
```

For your information: The timezone is needed because we convert local details like year, month, day, hour etc to a global instant but your input does not contain any zone or offset information. Therefore it is necessary to supply the formatter with a zone or offset.

As you can see, `SimpleDateFormat` and Joda-Time use the system timezone by default (implicitly). However, the `java.time`-API and Time4J require to explicitly specify a timezone (IMHO the cleaner design).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse("mydate",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"));
System.out.println(date.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

Comment: This give me:
Text '20140920111703000' could not be parsed at index 0